# c++ How to get arity of a constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, arity

Given a template parameter class `T` that has a **single** constructor (*no copy or move constructor either*) and **zero** default arguments, is there some way to find the arity of `T(...)`?

My attempts so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename F> struct function_arity;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct function_arity<R (Args...)>
    : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Args)> {};

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct function_arity<R (*)(Args...)> : function_arity<R (Args...)> {};

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct function_arity<R (&)(Args...)> : function_arity<R (Args...)> {};

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct function_arity<R (C::*)(Args...) const> : function_arity<R (Args...)> {};

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
struct function_arity<R (C::*)(Args...)> : function_arity<R (Args...)> {};

template <typename C>
struct function_arity : function_arity<decltype(&C::operator())> {};

struct no_copy { no_copy() = default; no_copy(const no_copy&) = delete; };
struct no_move { no_move() = default; no_move(no_move&&) = delete; };

struct A : no_copy, no_move { A(int, float) { std::cout << "A!\n"; }; };
struct B : no_copy, no_move { B(double) { std::cout << "B!\n"; }; };
struct C : no_copy, no_move { C() { std::cout << "C!\n"; }; };

int main()
{
    std::cout << function_arity<&A::A>::value << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are still copy constructor...

Comment: @Jarod No, it and the move constructor are marked as deleted.  There is only **one** constructor available.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez: I mean that deleted functions are part of overload [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bae194578965da1).

Comment: @Jarod then is this just impossible?

Comment: @BrianRodriguez It's possible if the types are known.

Comment: @Columbo Well, the types should _theoretically_ be known statically (That's how I'll be using this).  Do you mean I'd have to explicitly list the types when I try to deduce them?  That'd kind of defeat my goal here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we make the following assumptions:

- The parameters are either fixed types or (entirely unrestricted!) catch-all parameters (not e.g. `std::basic_string<CharT>`)
- The parameters are MoveConstructible

, then

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace detail {
    template <typename Ignore>
    struct anything {
        template <typename T,
                  typename=std::enable_if_t<not std::is_same<Ignore, std::decay_t<T>>{}>>
        operator T&&();
    };

    template <typename U, typename=void, typename... args>
    struct test : test<U, void, args..., anything<U>> {};
    template <typename U, typename... args>
    struct test<U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<U, args...>{}
                                 && sizeof...(args) < 32>, args...>
        : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(args)> {};
    template <typename U, typename... args>
    struct test<U, std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(args) == 32>, args...>
        : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, (std::size_t)-1> {};
}

template <typename U>
using ctor_arity = detail::test<U, void>;
```

…should work as expected. [**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/908856137a988eb8).
Note that the above approach is easily translatable into C++11.